# Some group members of AD user groups are not synced when using Azure AD Connect

Tags: entra-id

When we started syncing our on-prem AD to our Azure AD instance, we noticed that in some circumstances the groups on Azure AD does not contain all the members that the on-prem group has.

Having gone through the recommendations of IdFix, we couldn't find the reason for this mismatch. All the users were synced correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that if the Primary Group of the user in the on-prem AD is not "Domain Users", syncing of these users' group memberships is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

By default,  the primary group of active directory users is **Domain Users**. There is no need to change primary group unless you have Macintosh clients or POSIX-compliant applications.

If you change the default Primary Group to a new one, for example there are two users: *aadu01* and *aadu02*, both of the two users are belong to group *aadg*. The user *aadu02*, set the group *aadg* as Primary Group(See screenshot 1), then, the **member** attribute for group *aadg* will exclude the user *aadu02*, and only the user *aadu01* will be included in the member attribute (See screenshot 2).

During Azure AD Connect synchronization, the **member** attribute of group will be synced to Azure AD, and based on the **member** attribute,  only the user *aadu01* will be associated with group *aadg*.

However, the user *aadu02* still can be synced to Azure AD if the user is included in synchronization scope, such as Users, Domain Users, and so on, but it will not show up in the group aadg.

To resolve this issue, it's recommended to change the primary group to Domain Users.

Screenshot 1

[image]

Screenshot 2

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what happened in our case... from your example, aadu01 and aadu02 were both members of aadg. aadu01's primary group is Domain Users, aadu02's primary group was Test Azure Group. In this scenario, aadu02's membership to aadg would not sync.